# KeyPress and KeyDown events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Hello I'm trying to make a program in WF that uses the KeyPress event.
I've written the following code:

```
 private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
     while (true)
     {
         switch (e.KeyChar)
         {
                    case (char)68:
                        MessageBox.Show("Test");
                        break;
         }
      }
}
```

But when I execute the program and press the key the message box doensn;t appear.
Does anyone have any suggestions or knows how to fix this?
I've also been told that a     KeyDown event could work but I don't know how to work with those either.

Comment: Is this real code? It will hang your app independently of the actual key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `while(true)` in an event handler.  It will loop infinitely.

Just do

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyChar)
    {
        case (char)68:
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
            break;
    }
}
```

Also is seems cleaner to compare the pressed key to the *actual character* rather than the ASCII code:

```
    switch (e.KeyChar)
    {
        case 'D':
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set [Form.KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

e.g.
In your form

```
this.KeyPreview =true;
```